# Plotly in R: how to increase the space between bars?

Tags: r, plotly

friends!

If I plot a bar charts using plotly in R, by default I have no spacing between bars.

My questions are:

1. How to increase the space between bars? (see the pic)
2. How to avoid overlapping of text and bars? (see the pic)

Thanks a lot!

[image: illustration]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add the code for creating the example? Ideally to have a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example": stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add the code for creating the example? Ideally to have a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example": stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when using a numeric x axis... try putting as.factor(VARIABLE)

example: count the number of rows that contain the graduating class of the 
df = data frame you are plotting; x = variable you are plotting

plot_ly(df, x = df$x)

```
 -this gives you a messy looking blob
```

plot_ly(df, x = as.factor(df$x))

```
 -now it is known that your x axis is a factor, it will separate each value and break it up with a space in between
```